# Select the 'earliest n' or 'latest n' entries of a subset in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a trading log for Eve Online and I need to keep track of average sale prices for arbitrary items.  I do a sum of FILTER results to find the total cost of all of a particular item and then divide by the count to find the average.  The problem is, I want to keep a more accurate rolling average of my current stock only, i.e. I want to only use the latest N entries from my FILTER results, where N is number bought minus number sold.  Conversely, when calculating profit it would be more accurate to only count entries which have already been sold, i.e. the earliest ones.

Is there a way to do this?  The only way I could think of would be using a for loop to count backwards from the end of the list, but I don't know how to do that in a spreadsheet. These are the formula I'm currently using:

```
Item
=UNIQUE(B3:B)

Bought
=SUM(FILTER( D:D , B:B = Q3))

Sold
=SUM(FILTER( L:L , J:J = Q3))

In Stock
=R3-S3

Avg. Buy Value
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER( E:E , B:B = Q3)," ISK","")))))/R3

Avg. Sell Value
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER( M:M , J:J = Q3)," ISK","")))))/S3

Avg. Profit
=V3+U3

Total Profit
=W3*S3

Avg ROI
=-W3/U3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `filter` is intuitive, [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) is a more powerful tool, and is better suited for your task.

Suppose A has the timestamp, B the type of product, and C the data you want to average. The command

```
=query(A:C, "select C where B = 'ProductName' order by A desc limit 10")
```

selects 10 most recent transactions for the given product name. If you want to average these, put the average around the command:

```
=average(query(A:C, "select C where B = 'ProductName' order by A desc limit 10"))
```

To take the 10 oldest instead of 10 newest, change `desc` (descending) to `asc` (ascending).

To use the product name contained in another cell (e.g., F1), insert it by concatenation:

```
=average(query(A:C, "select C where B = '"&F1&"' order by A desc limit 10"))
```

Comment: This is what I was having trouble with; I couldn't figure out how to put a variable in the query.  `=average(query(A:C, "select C where B = '"&F1&"' order by A desc limit 10"))`

Comment: The problem I'm having now is that the number of items isn't necessarily the limit value.  If I want the first N items, I may have to use the first M entries because entries may consist of several of the same item.  I figure I could use a `while` clause, using an iterative sum of the item count, but there doesn't appear to be a while clause in the query language docs.

Comment: I think you'll need a helper table for that: something that aggregates the results of the first table, eliminating repetitions. Then you can query that table.

Comment: The problem is not that I have repititions, it's that I have some entries that count double or triple (because it's a sale of two or three items).  Is there no way to do a cumulative sum?

Comment: It would help to see a sample of your data. But, as a separate question, because this one is about selecting "latest n" and it has been answered.

Comment: [New question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/84461/iterative-sums-in-google-sheets)